# Only one device can't reach website on my home network

Tags: windows, networking, dns

I have multiple devices in my home network, Windows 10/11, Android, iPhone. And one of them a Dell XPS 7590 laptop with Windows 11 can’t reach out to `code.jquery.com` which results in multiple websites not loading correctly.

The problem only appears with this device (Dell XPS 7590 laptop) and I can’t find the problem nor a solution. It doesn’t matter which Browser (Edge, Chrome, Firefox) I use. The problem persists.

I receive this error message:

```
Website not reachable / ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

It appears to be a problem specific to this device. I've tried the following:

- Freshly installed Windows 11
- Freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04
- Tried a few different ipv4/6 dns servers (local)
- Tried a few different ipv4/6 dns servers in FRITZ!Box.
- Changed ip address in my FRITZ!Box.
- Disabled firewall.
- Changed firewall.
- Checked host file. Nothing suspicious.
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/connection-resets-on-certain-websites-how-do-i-fix/a0ba427b-2658-4b64-8c13-3aa864611145

What I can do is ping `code.jquery.com`, that works.
The response is

```
Antwort von 2001:4de0:ac18::1:a:1b: Zeit=23ms
```

And after `ipconfig /flushdns` the website opens once but won’t load if embeded on other pages.

What seams to “fix” the error, is when I connect to a VPN I can reach `code.jquery.com`. But that’s not a practical solution.

Also it works if I change the Wi-Fi to my mobile hotspot which is connected to the same Wi-Fi as the laptop. Or if I disable IPv6 on my Wi-Fi Adapter

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like a block of your IPv6 address somewhere.  Are your other devices using IPv6?

Comment: yes they are also using ipv6

Comment: currently after restarting my dell xps, I can access this site for a few seconds before it becomes unreachable

Comment: There was a Windows 11 Pro cumulative update and .NET Framework update this past week (well after January Patch Tuesday).  Have you done these update?  And then if so, register a case with Microsoft.

Comment: This Update is installed. The problem appears before and after

Comment: I don't know - the site works here: two Windows 11 machines.